# Multidimensional array not returning the right values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array that I am trying to work with, here is what it looks like.

```
$states = array(
"California" => array(
    "state" => "California",
    "abbr" => "CA",
    "city" => "Sacramento",
    "county" => "Sacramento",
    "zip" => "95632"
),
"Washington" => array(
    "state" => "Washington",
    "abbr" => "WA",
    "city" => "Seattle",
    "county" => "King",
    "zip" => "98101"
),
"Texas" => array(
    "state" => "Texas",
    "abbr" => "TX",
    "city" => "San Antonio",
    "county" => "Bexar",
    "zip" => "78251"
),
"Florida" => array(
    "state" => "Florida",
    "abbr" => "FL",
    "city" => "Orlando",
    "county" => "Orange",
    "zip" => "32801"
),
);
```

When I run a foreach loop to get the keys from the first level of the arrays I get the expected output of

```
California Washington Texas Florida
```

However I need to access the second level of the array. For example I need California['abbr'] so this is the code I run:

```
foreach (array_keys($states) as $state) {
    echo $state['abbr'];
}
```

Instead of getting

```
CA WA TX FL
```

like I would expect I'm getting

```
C W T F
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array_keys($states)` is returning

```
 array("California", "Washington", "Texas", "Florida")
```

So the `foreach` loop is echoing just the first character of each state.  Loop through the entire array instead of just the keys:

```
foreach ($states as $name => $details) {
    echo $details['abbr'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use two foreach in order to access the elements inside each cities (array). That's not the fastest way but it's good to know it.

```
// access the first layer
foreach($states as $state)
{
  // access the second layer
  foreach($state as $key => $element)
  {
    // if the key is equal to 'abbr', echo it's value
    echo ($key == 'abbr') ? $state[$key] : '';
    echo '  ';
  }
}
```

This will output:

> CA WA TX FL

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach(array_keys($states) as $state) {
    echo $state;
}
```

Will echo the keys, because you're looping over the keys, not the array. To get the abbreviation, you should do

```
foreach($states as $state) {
    echo $state['abbr'];
}
```

If you want to loop over both the key and the value at the same time, try this

```
foreach($states as $key=>$state) {
    echo "$key: {$state['abbr']}";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just:

```
foreach($states as $state) {
     foreach($state as $v) {
         echo $v['abbr'];
     }
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

Only cut out `array_keys`. You need whole element of that array, not only keys of array.

```
foreach ($states as $state)
{
    echo $state['abbr'];
}
```